# osgi blueprint how to read resource file in bundle

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I use osgi and blueprint, i search how to read file in my bundle?
Such as :
mybundle

- file.json
- OSGI-INF/blueprint/blueprint.xml
- WEB-INF
- ***

I want read file.json in myservice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To do this, the easy method is to inject bundlecontext in your bean

**blueprint.xml**

```
<bean id="plugin" class="com.timactive.MyBean" init-method="start">
    <property name="bcontext" ref="blueprintBundleContext"></property>
 </bean>
```

The possible reference :

**blueprintBundle**
Provides bundle's Bundle object.

**blueprintBundleContext**
Provides bundle's BundleContext object.

**blueprintContainer**
Provides the BlueprintContainer object for the bundle.

**blueprintConverter**
Provides the Converter object for the bundle that provides access to the Blueprint Container type conversion facility. Type conversion has more information.
source:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-osgiblueprint/

And in your class :

```
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext
public class MyBean  {

    public BundleContext bcontext;
    public boolean start(){
    try {
    Bundle bundle = bcontext.getBundle();
    InputStream is = bundle.getEntry("/file.json").openStream();
    String jsondb =  readFile(is);

    } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error("The file treefield.json not found", e);
                return(false);
            }

        }

        return(true);
    }

    private String readFile(InputStream is ) throws IOException {
        java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
   }
   public void setBcontext(BundleContext bcontext) {
    this.bcontext = bcontext;
}
```

Comment: These bean references are specified in section 121.11.1 Environment managers of the Blueprint Specification https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.blueprint.html#d0e87086